# Lowest Latency with java and OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using opencv 3.0 on Java, and I want the lowest LATENCY possible.
I'm grabbing images from DirectShow of Windows 8 (connected to a BlackMagic Intensity Pro USB 3.0).

How can I do it?
What improvement should I have to make?

To capture new frames I just use:

```
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
...

VideoCapture sorgente = new VideoCapture(0);
sorgente.grab();
sorgente.retrieve(mat);
```